# Dokka uses fully qualified class names

Tags: kotlin, kdoc, kotlin-dokka

I'm using dokka to auto generate javadoc for me. Though when it encounters any class not from my project it uses fully qualified names.

Is it possible to use only class names and make dokka provide a link for it? For example:

```
java.lang.String getName()
```

I'd want instead of `java.lang.String` to have `String` with link to [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

My gradle config:

```
ext.simpleName = project.name.substring(project.name.indexOf('-') + 1, project.name.size())

dokka {
    outputFormat = 'javadoc'
    outputDirectory = "${rootProject.buildDir}/javadoc/$project.ext.simpleName"
    linkMapping {
        dir = 'src/main/java'
        url = "https://github.com/mibac138/ArgParser/blob/master/$project.ext.simpleName/src/main/java"
    }
    linkMapping {
        dir = 'src/main/kotlin'
        url = "https://github.com/mibac138/ArgParser/blob/master/$project.ext.simpleName/src/main/kotlin"
    }
}
```

Also, what exactly is `linkMapping`? I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 2):

For linking to 3rd party libraries you should use `externalDocumentationLink` pointing to Oracle Java documentation:

```
dokka{    
    externalDocumentationLink {
        url = new URL("https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/")
    }
```

If you use Kotlin and Java in the same project fully qualified names for Java classes may be necessary